# How to Copy and Insert rows into same dataframe based on count

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this (obviously with few variables compared to original data I need to work on with)

```
woe <- c('1:woe', '2:woe', '3:woe', '4:woe', '5:woe')
svi <- c('stated','verified','verified','stated','stated')
fico_avg <-  ceiling(runif(5,750, 780))
count <- c(8,12,34,24,7)
df <- data.frame(cbind(woe,svi,fico_avg,count))

  woe      svi   fico_avg count
 1:woe   stated      771     8
 2:woe verified      759    12
 3:woe verified      752    34
 4:woe   stated      776    24
 5:woe   stated      767     7
```

I would like to create a dataset with first row repeating 8 times( filling first 8 rows), second row repeating 12 times, third one 34 times depending on the value of variable 'count' . I tried lookup the function InsertRow() in DataCombine package. InsertRow() require RowNum as one of the argument to insert newrow. the RawNum changes as I insert newrows into the frame. Basic idea is to extract each row from original dataframe copy it x time ( if count=x) and finally row bind all those rows into one frame. Any help is appretiated. Thanks in advance

Comment: use `rep` and `lapply` with a final `rbind`.

Comment: @anand Please don't use `data.frame(cbind(..`  just `data.frame` would be sufficient when you have columns with different `class`.  You can check the `str(df)`.  Here `count` column is `factor` as a result of first creating `matrix` and then converting to `data.frame`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dataset is large - probably this should be Quicker

```
df <- data.frame(woe,svi,fico_avg,count)
df[rep(seq.int(1,nrow(df)), df$count),]
```

Works.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
outdf = df
outdf = outdf[-c(1:nrow(outdf)),]

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    for(j in 1:df[i,]$count) outdf[nrow(outdf)+1,]= df[i,]
}
outdf
```

You should use:

```
df <- data.frame(woe,svi,fico_avg,count)
```

rather than

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(woe,svi,fico_avg,count))
```

No need for cbind here. It actually converts your count variable from numeric to a factor variable.

Comment: thank you so much, it works verywell. On that note, my dataset was in datatable format, I had to convert the data back into dataframe format and then it start working. I have noticed previously that several routine operations I used to perform on dataframe sometimes error out in datatable format

Comment: @anand, if you're using "data.table" why are you asking for a `data.frame` answer? If you have a `data.table`, you can just do `dt[rep(sequence(nrow(dt)), count)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df_long <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$count), ]
```

Hope it helps